# is it possible to send email as xml data with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, html-email

is it possible to send user and email in xml format that is formatted using xslt styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send any text in email. Doesn't matter if you formatted it via XSLT or any other way. You of course *can* send XML and an XSLT stylesheet with it, but this is not a very good idea.

You can't rely on the receiving client to be able to transform XML - most email clients do not have an XSLT processor built in (nor any understanding of XML). They are mostly text readers.

Use the resulting text of the transformation in your email, and you should be fine.

Of course, this is light in details, but so is your question.

Comment: I think he meant sending the email in XML and XSLT so that the translation happens on the client side.

Comment: @Assaf Lavie - I see. Will update my answer to reflect. Toda.

Comment: Note that email receivers often handle HTML, so you could transform the XML on the server side into HTML and pipe the output into an MIME email body.